# Why flashplayer does not need JVM?

Tags: java, actionscript, flash

I have been developing ActionScript apps for half a year or so. As far as I can see, mxmlc compiler is just a sh-script to call *javac --{options}* in more convenient way. This gives me an idea that my source code is compiled into *native* java byte-code.

From all above I can conclude that either Flash Player should require JVM installed or be *a JVM* itself. Or maybe Java is used to generate Adobe custom binary file just as any other compiler would do, but Java is cross-platform and an industry standard, so to avoid portability problems Adobe (Macromedia) could choose in for ActionScript/Flex.

Can you explain to me this?

Comment: By `java --{options}`, do you mean `javac --{options}`? I doubt very highly that ActionScript compiles to java byte code. Could you post the script lines in the mxmlc compiler that makes you assert that "source code is compiled into native java byte-code"

Comment: Sorry, mistype, javac. That's why I thought that just like Groovy, Scala, J{Ruby, Python, smth} it should run on JVM (maybe not the original JVM from Oracle or the one from OpenJDK)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The development environment for ActionScript is written in Java, but compiling ActionScript does not result in a Java-compatible binary. Instead, it compiles to a binary which runs on the ActionScript Virtual Machine. So Flash Player has a virtual machine, but it is not Java-related.

Comment: This is indeed the answer, plain and simple. (You're also mixing up `java`, the Java runtime and `javac`, the Java compiler.) If the compiler was written in Python, it'd be invoked `python ...` but still would not result in Python code.

Comment: However, one should recognize it could be a good thing to have a kind of flex-on-java, which will be easier now that flex is supposed to become open-source.